# Javascript - Functions Conflict

Tags: javascript

I use Filtrify plugin for filtering by advanced tag. This [link](https://github.com/luis-almeida/filtrify/blob/master/music.html) is an example I used.

I focus this script on html file

```
$(function() {
    $.filtrify("container", "placeHolder");
});
```

and

```
<div id="placeHolder"></div>
<ul id="container">...</ul>
```

When I add the script code below on html file, it only show  `<ul id="container">` not show `<div id="placeHolder">`.

My script I added

```
function $(element) {
    return document.getElementById(element);   
}
```

Please explain why and how can I add the script above?

Comment: Why do you want the `$(element)` function?

Comment: I want get the element with somethings.
`var element = document.getElementById("...");`

Comment: But you can do that with jQuery already or with `document.getElementById`. Why do you want this to be mapped to `$` in particular *and* still use jQuery while still using `$` to refer to jQuery, as well? That is my question. Your situation does have a solution - you can make jQuery relinquish `$` but by far the easiest thing to do is to not purposefully trying to get your code in a mess. So I wonder why you are doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have jQuery and your own function both providing a value for a variable called `$`.

Rename one of the `$` functions.