# What is the different between "function $()" and "$(function())"?

Tags: javascript

What is different between `function $() {}` and `$(function() { });` ?

How and I rewrite this code by another way?

```
function $(a) {
  return document.getElementById(a)
}
```

Comment: `How and I rewrite this code by another way?` why do you want that?

Comment: you still not convinced about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558887/javascript-functions-conflict

Answer (score 2):

`function $() {}` declares a new function with the name `$`.

`$(...)` calls a function named `$`.

`$(function() { })` calls a function named `$` and passes a function as an argument to it.